# How to show inputs element if checkbox is checked? angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to display a input element if a checkbox is checked using ng-if ,and at the same time if I check multiple checkboxes multiple input is displayed because I want to enter the quantity of each item,but now even i check a checkbox no input displayed .
thanks in advance

```
     <nz-form-item >
     <nz-form-label  nzRequired nzFor="item">items </nz-form-label>
      <nz-form-control   nzErrorTip="Ce champ est obligatoire">

      <div id="bloc1">
      <div nz-col >  <label nz-checkbox  nz-col  formControlName="checkedValue" *ngFor="let 
      item of items "  [nzValue]="item"  (ngModelChange)="showInput()"> 
      {{item.name}}</label>  </div>
    </div>
     </nz-form-control>

    <nz-form-label   nzRequired nzFor="quantite" >Quantité </nz-form-label>
        <nz-form-control   nzErrorTip="Ce champ est obligatoire">
          <div id="bloc2" >

          <nz-input-number *ngIf="showMe" formControlName="quantite"  [nzStep]="1" 
         [nzSize]="'small'"></nz-input-number>
          </div>

        </nz-form-control>


  </nz-form-item>
```

.ts

```
showMe:boolean=false;

showInput(){
    this.showMe!=this.showMe;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have seems like it should be working. probably an issue with your directives.

or at least you can use the state of the checkbox directly like:

```html
<label nz-checkbox  nz-col  formControlName="checkedValue" *ngFor="let 
      item of items "  [nzValue]="item" [(ngModel)]=isShowingInput> 
      {{item.name}}</label>
<div *ngIf=isShowingInput>
```

working demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vj2qms?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem is that now I can only check one checkbox and display a single input, in my case I want for each checkbox we can display a corresponding input

Answer (score 0):

I used 'nzChecked':

```
<label nz-checkbox nzChecked="true" (nzCheckedChange)="addOrRemove()"></label>
```

It does not have in document, but it still works.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Never post code as image. Post code as text and format it with (CTRL-K) or manually apply spce and {}.